# Object not set to instance of object in Azure Emulator Model View

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, nullreferenceexception

I have an exception caused by a direct copy of another code which follows:

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Pictures()
    {
        picturesList.Clear();
        CloudTable table = _Service.GetCloudTable();
        CloudBlobContainer blob = _Service.GetCloudBlobContainer();

        TableQuery<PictureEntity> query = new TableQuery<PictureEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "hiltihaningepictures"));

        foreach (PictureEntity pic in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
        {
            picturesList.Add(pic);
        }

        picturesList.Sort();
        return PartialView();
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<WebRole.Models.PictureEntity>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#main-slider').liquidSlider({
        height: '525px',
        minHeight: '525px',
        dynamicArrows: true,
        dynamicArrowsGraphical: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        continuous: true,
        autoSlide: true,
        pauseOnHover: true
    });
});
/* If you need to access the internal property or methods, use this:
var api = $.data( $('#slider-id')[0], 'liquidSlider');
*/
</script>
<div id="main_liquid" style="display: none;">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="liquid-slider" id="main-slider">
        <div>
            <img src="@item.Url" class="intro_img_group" />
            <p>Uppladdad av: @item.Uploader, @item.Timestamp.DateTime</p>
            <p>Beskrivning: @item.Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The only difference is that the other view, which work just fine and dandy, doesn't contain the Javascript section. Other than that completely identical.

Exception details:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=App_Web_v2igssw5
StackTrace:
at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Pictures_cshtml.Execute() in g:\HiltiHaninge\HiltiHaninge\Views\Home\Pictures.cshtml:line 23
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

It's recommendening me to use keyword new but I dont' know what to do

Comment: Not 100% sure but shouldn't you be returning the model back from controller action? Something like `return PartialView(picturesList);`.

Comment: The message also tells you to look at *line 23* of Pictures.cshtml. What is there? Did you initialize the variable? If this is the Model, the error is expected because you forgot to return it.

Comment: Oh my god I missed that one Gaurav....haha sorry you guys. Thanks for help though!